# Fade in div in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, fade

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="userRow in users.items track by $index">
    <div class="col-sm-4" ng-repeat="user in userRow">
        <div class="tile {[{ user.col}]}">
            <h3 class="title">{[{ user.name }]} <span class="pull-right">{[{ user.id }]}</span></h3>
            <h4>{[{ user.phone}]}</h4>
            <p>{[{ user.email }]} <span class="pull-right">{[{ user.role }]}</span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have some JS code that pushes items on to the list:

```
var items = response.data;

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    self.items.push(items[i]);
    //...
```

When this happens - the page updates as you'd expect.

The only thing I want differently, is for the div's to **fade in** instead of just appearing.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the angular animation module: `ngAnimate`. Include the module js in your html `<script src="angular-animate.js">` and inject it in your app with: `angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']);`.

You find the documentation and examples under: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate

> The following directives are "animation aware":
>
> ngRepeat :    enter, leave and move

Give your html div elements the class `fade` and then create this css to animate the fade in:

```
/* The starting CSS styles for the enter animation */
.fade.ng-enter {
  transition:0.5s linear all;
  opacity:0;
}

/* The finishing CSS styles for the enter animation */
.fade.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried this - but the items are not fading in. They just "appear". I've tried adding it to both `<div class="fade col-sm-4" ng-repeat="user in userRow">` and `<div class="fade tile {[{ user.col}]}">` but the same thing happens for both. How can I debug this?

Comment: Maybe the error is logged in console, press F12 in your browser to open console.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with CSS animations. For this you can build your own thing but I guess you are better of using [ng-animate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) (an Angular module).

This module adds and removes specific classes to the element when it is added and/or removed. Based on that classes you can apply your css animation. I suggest you read the docs to see how this works.

Answer (score 0):

[`ngRepeat` supports the `enter`, `leave` and `move` animation hooks](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#animations). So you can simply add a class to your `div`s and add [`ngAnimate`-CSS rules](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate#css-based-animations).

**Css:**

```
.fade {
    transition: opacity .5s;
}

.fade.ng-enter, .fade.ng-leave-active {
    opacity: 0;
}

.fade.ng-leave, .fade.ng-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Then just add the `fade`-class to your repeated `div`, to make it fade in and out. Do not forget to add `ngAnimate` to your main `module`'s-dependencies!

Answer (score -1):

Also you can find the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rpk98c/6t42m/1/) for ng-animate in js-fiddle.

```js
angular.module('MyApp', []);

function App($scope) {
  $scope.names = [];
  var data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    data.push('item' + i)
  }
  $scope.add = function() {
    if (data.length) $scope.names.splice(0, 0, data.pop());
  };
  $scope.remove = function(index) {
    $scope.names.splice(index, 1);
  };
}
```

```css
.repeat-enter-setup,
.repeat-leave-setup,
.repeat-move-setup {
  -webkit-transition: all linear 1s;
  -moz-transition: all linear 1s;
  -ms-transition: all linear 1s;
  -o-transition: all linear 1s;
  transition: all linear 1s;
}
.repeat-enter-setup {
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
.repeat-enter-setup.repeat-enter-start {
  max-height: 250px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.repeat-leave-setup {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 250px;
}
.repeat-leave-setup.repeat-leave-start {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
}
.repeat-move-setup {} .repeat-move-setup.repeat-move-start {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="App">
  <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
  <ul>
    <li ng-animate="{enter: 'repeat-enter',
                        leave: 'repeat-leave',
                        move: 'repeat-move'}" ng-click="remove($index)" ng-repeat="name in names">{{name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```